# Errors after Firebase update from 16.0.7 to 17.2.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

I have `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'` and it works great!

After update to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'` I have so many problems:

[image]

**Module: app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "free.success.kneu"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 223
        versionName "2.2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Project**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: did you use the google play services..?

Comment: `implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'` - gradle

Comment: pls try this my solution.